# Java 7 to Java 8 using streams

Tags: java-8

Converting the below code from Java 7 to Java 8 using streams

Java 7:

```
if (Objects.nonNull(input.getList())) {
    if (Objects.nonNull(input.getId()) && !input.getList().contains(input.getId())) {
        input.getList().add(input.getId());
    }
} else if (Objects.nonNull(input.getId())) {
    List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();
    ids.add(input.getId());
    input.setList(ids);
}
```

I tried something like this but it does not work properly.

Java 8

```
Stream.concat(input.getList().stream(),
                input.getList().stream().filter(list2 -> !input.getList().contains(input.getId())));
```

`Input` class has two fields `List<Long> list` and `Long id`
Can someone please correct where I am missing.

Comment: In Java 7, there is no `java.util.Objects.nonNull` method. But it’s not clear why you use that method anyway, instead of a straight-forward `… != null` expression. Besides that, the purpose of the Stream API is not to modify collections. That’s what the modification methods of the Collection API are for. In other words, the code you labelled as “Java 7” is already the idiomatic Java code, regardless of the version.

Comment: Agreed the snippet is actually Java 8 only but I am more interested on how to achieve it using streams.

Comment: That’s like asking how to use a car to do the laundry. It’s not what the Stream API is for and any attempt to creatively abuse that API for this task will end up in code that is either, more complicated or less efficient, or even both. And by the way, why is your first attempt full of `null` checks and your second hasn’t any of them? In general, it is a good idea to always initialize collection fields, so they never can be `null`, but then, the idiomatic solution would be even simpler.